# Using chunked transfer encoding to send data obtained by rolling Curl

Tags: php, curl, chunked-encoding

I am using rolling curl to get data from 40 other websites. As soon as the results are available for a website, they are being sent out immediately by using chunks.

To implement that , I added following headers :-

```
header("Transfer-encoding: chunked");
flush();
```

I also used a function to print the chunks :-

```
function print_chunks($chunk){
    $chunk = json_encode($tempArray);
    echo sprintf("%x\r\n", strlen(($chunk)));
    print_r($chunk);
   echo "\r\n";
   flush();
}
```

In my case , every chunk is some data in JSON format, whose size can be any value other than zero.

At the client side, I am using this to handle my responses :-

```
xml.onprogress = function () {
alert("Triggered");
}
```

That triggers only twice for about 40 calls . I guess many responses are getting merged before they are actually sent out. This leads to severely bad performance as results are sent out not individually, but only after all results have been sent out.Is it due to small size of individual responses ?

[Here](http://compare.buyhatke.com/example.php?searchText=Dumb%20and%20dumber) is the actual handle which sends chunked data to check out.

**Update :**

Is there any constraint on the minimum size of individual chunks ? If I sent only simple small string chunks, it sends all of my chunks together.

This is the complete code that i used. Even if I have made 10 chunks here, I get all of them together after 20 seconds :-

```
<?php
header("Transfer-encoding: chunked");
flush();


function dump_chunk($chunk)
{
    echo sprintf("%x\r\n", strlen($chunk));
    echo $chunk;
    echo "\r\n";
    flush();
}

$string = "Hello World, This is chunk1";
$string1 = "Hello World, This is chunk2";
$string2 = "Hello World, This is chunk3";
$string3 = "Hello World, This is chunk4";
$string4 = "Hello World, This is chunk5";
$string5 = "Hello World, This is chunk6";
$string6 = "Hello World, This is chunk7";
$string7 = "Hello World, This is chunk8";
$string8 = "Hello World, This is chunk9";
$string9 = "Hello World, This is chunk10";
$string10 = "";

dump_chunk($string);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string1);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string2);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string3);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string4);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string5);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string6);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string7);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string8);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string9);
sleep(2);
dump_chunk($string10);

?>
```

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt.

Comment: Are you using any Apache module that interferes with buffering, such as `mod_gzip`?

Comment: No, I am not using any other module

Comment: Is there any online debugger where I can submit my handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php%5D%28flush%28%29%29) to push the content to the browser, at the end of your `print_chunks`function, should work.

Comment: I used that actually. I forgot to post it here. Can u check the handle that I have provided to find out how many of chunks of data is coming http://compare.buyhatke.com/example.php?searchText=Dumb%20and%20dumber

Comment: That's just giving me an empty page. nothing, not even on the source-code.

Comment: Please wait for 30 seconds approx. Also make sure that there is some searchText at the end

Comment: Hmm, it's not working here. I'll assume it's my awful connection's fault.